# is that possible to covert the String

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my string date from API "AUG 26 2020"

need to covert as "AUG 26"

the data which i get from API is

````
{
"AUG 26 2020" :1234,
"AUG 27 2020" :1234,
"AUG 28 2020" :1234,
"AUG 29 2020" :1234,
}```
````

Comment: Please attach what have you tried?

Comment: Iterate using `Object.entries` or `Object.keys` and extract string what you want. If fails post it here

Comment: See [the MDN docs on string.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: `"AUG 26 2020".split(' ').slice(0, 2).join(' ');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you want is simply removing the last few digits of the year with the space before it, you could achieve it with simple string manipulation

```js
const data = {
  "AUG 26 2020" :1234,
  "AUG 27 2020" :1234,
  "AUG 28 2020" :1234,
  "AUG 29 2020" :1234,
}

const output = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([key, val])=> [key.substr(0, key.length-5), val]))

console.log(output)
```